# How to avoid orphan line of multipage tabular?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable, widows-orphans

There is an orphan line on page 2.

How to get rid of it?

### Minimal Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array}


\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\pic{\begin{pspicture}(5,5)\psframe(5,5)\end{pspicture}}
\def\row{\pic&\pic\\\hline}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{m{0.4\linewidth}|}}
\hline
\row\row\row
\end{longtable}

\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{m{0.4\linewidth}|}}
\hline
\row\row\row
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a test  with `\Needspace` from package `needspace`  if there is enough space on the page for beginning the table, which first draws the rule and then decides if the next row could be set on the current page.

```
\documentclass[dvips]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=5cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,needspace}


\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\pic{\begin{pspicture}(5,5)\psframe(5,5)\end{pspicture}}
\def\row{\pic & \pic\\\hline}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{m{0.4\linewidth}|}}
\hline
\row\row\row
\end{longtable}

\Needspace*{5.5cm}
\begin{longtable}{|*{2}{m{0.4\linewidth}|}}\hline
\row\row\row
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the `\hline` of the next longtable. You could try e.g. `\Needspace{6cm}` (from the `needspace` package) before the second longtable to force a page break. Or enlarge the page a bit with `\enlargethispage{1cm}`.